# How to show Dynamic items (just)which are fit on the screen ( RecyclerView or Just LinearLayout )

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Basically, the backend(Firebase) returns 10 players but I want to show just which are can be shown on screen(1x-2x-3x). ( The texts are dynamic and this way RV items width is dynamic like a photo )

[image]

Comment: take a width of the screen and divide by the list items text size i think  it helps..

Comment: Is it best practice? For example, the first text size is 25 and second is 3 How do I convert text size to screen width?

Answer (score 0):

To convert text size to screen width, you can use `DisplayMetrics` in Kotlin like this.

```
val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)
val screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels
```

To find the width of a textViewReference us this: `textView.getWidth()`-> returns width in pixels. Now do your calculations to make it fit within the given screen width.

> You can do this for every other view like a cardView for example.

Hope this helps! :D